# How do I remove node groups from start-up file?

Tags: append

I have been trying to find an explanation for the nodes either not saving after being appended, only some being saved, or all being appended when I only selected 1, and I've come up with nothing.

I tried the following link for help for removing appended nodes, but it's not working.

[How can I remove a node group from my startup file?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65180/how-can-i-remove-a-node-group-from-my-startup-file)

That was after using the help given in the following link.

[Why are node groups not being saved in my startup file?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/77046/why-are-node-groups-not-being-saved-in-my-startup-file)

Also, the "less/more slider" node is in the screen cap, but it won't save in the start-up file when appended. A problem that got me started in this whole mess to begin with.

EDIT : Apparently, my question isn't focused or not clear. It's all in my first sentence.

I'm having multiple problems.
1) Can't save all the nodes I appended.
2) Can't remove unwanted nodes.
3) Appending more than chosen.

The pics are referring to what's happening, in relation to the links and their instructions.

I know questions like these need details, but jeebus. Any more and I feel like I would be holding a persons hand while walking through a park...explaining every step we took.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi. Your question seems to contain conflicting questions. Your title is about removing node groups but in the question body you ask why appended groups aren't being saved. Which is it, do you want node groups saved or removed? Please [edit] your question to make it a bit clearer what you actually want (and what those screenshots are meant to be showing).

Comment: I'm asking both questions because both problems are happening. I was able to append certain nodes, but now I can't filter out the ones I don't want AND can't append certain nodes AFTER the initial appending.

Multiple problems are happening. I thought that was obvious with my "problem that got me started" comment. As for the pics, they're showing what I tired to do to remove nodes I don't want in relation to the links and their instructions.

My list of problems is in the very first sentence. It's pretty obvious what's going on and for you to assume only 1 problem can exist is weird.